# How to publish my C++ application?

Tags: installation, publish, solution

I made a game in C++, using Visual Studio 2010. For this game I'm using OpenGL and GLUT, IrrKlang, ODE and fltk (so a buch of libs and dlls). I also have a folder of sounds and some text files. All paths are relative and my application works well from the environment (both debug and release modes). The exe files won't work though.

How do I make an installer kit for my application? My solution includes two projects.

I've done this before with XNA projects, but now it's completely different. Please do not refer me to msdn because I've been there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First you should decide on a setup authoring tool. Here is a list that can get you started: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

After that, try creating an installer with that tool. Most of them have tutorials and documentation which may help. If you encounter problems, you can then ask more specific questions.